# Select radio button value inside span using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, html

I have the following radio buttons:

```
<span id="ContactUs1_rdoPreferredLanguage">
  <input id="ContactUs1_rdoPreferredLanguage_0" type="radio" name="ContactUs1$rdoPreferredLanguage" value="c7956c71-53be-46c9-8be0-6e384724a672" />
  <label for="ContactUs1_rdoPreferredLanguage_0">English</label>

  <input id="ContactUs1_rdoPreferredLanguage_1" type="radio" name="ContactUs1$rdoPreferredLanguage" value="d0e789b7-f050-4676-bb9b-d40736022fae" />
  <label for="ContactUs1_rdoPreferredLanguage_1">Spanish</label>
</span>
```

What would be the best way to select one of these using jQuery? I tried the following and it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

```
var select = $("#ContactUs1_rdoPreferredLanguage > input[type='radio']");
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to do the following.

```
select.val(0); // select English
```

Comment: try $("#ContactUs1_rdoPreferredLanguage_0").val('0');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getter :

```
var selectedItem = $("#ContactUs1_rdoPreferredLanguage > input:checked").next().text();
```

setter :

```
$("#ContactUs1_rdoPreferredLanguage > label:contains(***language***)").prev().attr("checked","checked");
```

where language is the text value of the language which has to be selected

example :  if you want to select 'English'

```
var language = "English";

$("#ContactUs1_rdoPreferredLanguage > label:contains('"+language+"')").prev().attr("checked","checked");
```

Comment: No, you'd need `$("…label:contains('"+language+"')")…`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which one was selected, try this:

```
var id = $("#ContactUs1_rdoPreferredLanguage > input[name='ContactUs1$rdoPreferredLanguage']:checked")[0].id,
    language = $('label[for="' + id + '"]').text();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SxcXA/

---

If you're trying to select the English one, try this:

```
$('#ContactUs1_rdoPreferredLanguage_0').prop('checked', true);
```

and here's the fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/SxcXA/1/

Comment: Neither works I'm afraid: Error: `$("#ContactUs1_rdoPreferredLanguage_0").prop` is not a function.

Comment: @Fulvio - It seems you are using an older version of jQuery (prior to 1.6). Replace `.prop('checked', true)` with `.attr('checked', 'checked')` - See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SxcXA/2/).